# Break long codes snprintf format and arguments

Tags: c++

I want split arguments on same variable with += ?

```
    int QueryExecute = snprintf(UpdateQuery, sizeof(UpdateQuery),"One=%u, Two=%d,",One, Two);
```

Can i do like this ?

```
int QueryExecute = snprintf(UpdateQuery, sizeof(UpdateQuery),"One=%u, Two=%d,");
int QueryExecute += One, Two;
```

Bassicaly i want to split the format and the arguments in different variables.

Sorry for bad english

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  It sounds like you're trying to reduce the length of a line of code, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I try to reduce lenght by split the arguments from the format %u example.. In different lines

Answer (score 3):

> Can i do like this ?

No you cannot. But you can split the line, C++ generally don't care for whitespaces:

```
int QueryExecute = snprintf(UpdateQuery, sizeof(UpdateQuery), "One=%u, Two=%d,",
                            One, Two);
```

---

If this is not your line's width you care about, and want to provide the following parameters (`One` and `Two`) later, you can do so with [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind):

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
auto snprintf_later = std::bind(snprintf, UpdateQuery, sizeof(UpdateQuery), "One=%u, Two=%d,", _1, _2);
// ...
int QueryExecute = snprintf_later(One, Two);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to be as specific about where you're putting the string; I'd suggest using a string stream as it removes your need to worry about the types of one and two; as well as putting the variables in the location that they're going to get put into the stream:

```
#include <sstream>
```

and then the usage:

```
std::stringstream data;
data << "One=" << one
     << "Two=" << two;

std::string buffer = data.str();
```